# Calling MySQL Arithmetic Operators in one function?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to make and call all `MySQL` Arithmetic Operators `( +, -, /, *)` in one function, but I'm facing one problem with the parameter `m1`. I'm getting an error message that is saying:

```
Syntax error: unexpected 'm1' (Identifier)?
```

I already declared it as a numeric, and it is still showing me the same error. Does anyone have any idea how to solve it and run this function successfully on `MySQL Workbench 5.7`

This is the code, and the error is in the 5th line:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `Calculator` 

(m1 numeric (10,4), m2 numeric (10,4), m3  numeric (10,4), s  varchar (20))

RETURNS INTEGER


BEGIN

m1:=&m1

m2:=&m2

s:=&s

if s = '+' then

m3:=m1+m2

dbms_output.put_line(m1||s||m2||'='||m3)

else if s = '-' then

m3:=m1-m2

dbms_output.put_line(m1||s||m2||'='||m3)

else if s = '*' then

m3:=m1*m2

dbms_output.put_line(m1||s||m2||'='||m3)

else if s = '/' then

m3:=m1/m2

dbms_output.put_line(m1||s||m2||'='||m3);

end if

  exception

  when zero_divide then

  dbms_output.put_line('cant divide by zero')

end

/



RETURN 1;
END
```

Comment: Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':=&m1

m2:=&m2

s:=&s

if s = '+' then

m3:=m1+m2

dbms_output.put_line(m1||s||m' at line 10
SQL Statement:
CREATE FUNCTION `Calculator` 

(m1 numeric (10,4), m2 numeric (10,4), m3  numeric (10,4), s  varchar (20))

RETURNS INTEGER


BEGIN

m1:=&m1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple cases of trying to use Oracle database syntax in your code.

Oracle and MySQL are two different products, and you can't use the same syntax for both.

In MySQL:

- You must use `SET` to do assignment statements. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html
- You don't need `:=` where `=` would be sufficient to do an assignment in MySQL. It does no harm, but it's another clue that you're trying to use Oracle syntax.
- `exception` is Oracle syntax, not MySQL. You might have meant to use `SIGNAL` to throw an exception in MySQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html
- `dbms_output.put_line()` is for Oracle database, not MySQL (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm). You can't write output inside a MySQL function.

You should study MySQL syntax before you go any further.

Comment: Bill Karwin: 
Thank you so much for your clear and helpful answer, and you are right that I don't have enough experience in MySQL. I though that Oracle, SQL, and MySQL could have similar syntax.

Your time to answer this question is much appreciated.